# Get the first mysql database records that sum to a particular value

Tags: mysql, django, filter, django-filters

I have a Django  model that holds to-dos with an estimate of the amount of time it will take to complete each one:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Action Name", max_length=200, unique = True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Complete?")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField("Creation Date", default=datetime.now)
    time_estimate = models.IntegerField("Estimated Completion Time", choices = TIME_ESTIMATES, default = 15)
```

I want to query on all the incomplete actions ordered by creation_date to get actions whose summed time_estimate does not exceed a certain amount.

So let's say I have 5 actions:

```
Name: Action 1
time_estimate: 10

Name: Action 2
time_estimate: 20

Name: Action 3
time_estimate: 30

Name: Action 4
time_estimate: 40

Name: Action 5
time_estimate: 50
```

Assuming they are sorted in that order, and I get a time of 55 minutes, I want the filter to return Actions 1 and 2.  If I got 100 minutes, I'd want the filter to return Actions 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way, but I would likely do a loop summing total times until it exceeded the value:

```
time_allowed = 55
time_used = 0
actions = []

for a in Action.objects.filter(complete=False).order_by('creation_date'):
    if time_used + a.time_estimate <= time_allowed:
        time_used += a.time_estimate
        actions.append(a)

# actions is a list of actions which can be accomplished within the
# time_allowed threshhold, and you can loop them to display, or whatever you
# are trying to do with them.
```

If you wanted to make it more scalable, you could order by time_estimate (ASC) and add an else statement to break the for loop when the time_allowed is exceeded. Like this:

```
time_allowed = 55
time_used = 0
actions = []

for a in Action.objects.filter(complete=False).order_by('time_estimate', 'creation_date'):
    if time_used + a.time_estimate <= time_allowed:
        time_used += a.time_estimate
        actions.append(a)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Sweet.  I didn't even think about it continuing to add tasks until time_used is as close to time_allowed as possible.  thanks.